# Function named and assigned to a variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Assign a function to a angularjs the scope of variable and assign a name to it is a bad practice?

Example for AngularJS doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

```
$scope.username = 'World';

$scope.sayHello = function() {
     $scope.greeting = 'Hello ' + $scope.username + '!';
};
```

'Bad Practice':

```
$scope.username = 'World';

$scope.sayHello = function helloWorld() {
     $scope.greeting = 'Hello ' + $scope.username + '!';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is bad practice and unnecessary confusion.

John Resig demonstrates the difference between the two in his Advanced JS Tutorial:

http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#11

```
var ninja = function myNinja(){ 
  assert( ninja == myNinja, "This function is named two things - at once!" ); 
}; 
ninja(); 
assert( typeof myNinja == "undefined", "But myNinja isn't defined outside of the function." ); 
log( ninja );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign angular score function you can it as first way.

```
$scope.sayHello = function() {
 $scope.greeting = 'Hello ' + $scope.username + '!';
};
```

but if you really want to assign a function to the angular mode you can use it like

```
var temp = function () { 
  console.info('temp');
}

$scope.sayHello = temp;
```

but at the end both will be same(declared as angular function) so better to follow first approach.